# How to boot an HTC Cha into Safe Mode

Tags: htc, safe-mode

On my HTC ChaCha I've been having problems with the bottom menu keys being periodically flakey and non responsive for which I wanted to try booting into Safe Mode to see if that fixes things.

Does anyone know the key combination  needed to  boot HTC ChaCha into safe mode?

I tried a generic HTC instruction I found online i.e. hold volume down key during reboot. But unfortunately that did not work.

Any other ideas?

Edit:

Android Version 2.3.3
HTC Sense: 2.1
Software number: 1.20.720.1

Kernel: 2.6.35.10-g28523b8

Answer (score 1):

Some instructions say hold Volume Down + Power 5 seconds to open the boot menu. On a ChaCha with software version 1.57.161.3 opens the boot menu immediately; I just hold Volume Down and get the boot menu within a second.

Booting works differently depending on which Android and ROM version you have. Open Settings, About this phone, Software and add in your question which version you have. On another ChaCha with software version 1.54.401.3 I get re reaction at all with holding Volume Down, but maybe the button is physically broken.

Update:

So 2.3.3, and presumably original ROM installed?

HTC did release updates from Android 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_ChaCha
Which phones got that update was supposedly Carrier-specific. I've seen mixed info on forums and official. On 12th June 2014 I tried (manually) to access the update servers listed in the ChaCha device props files (the ones used for OTA = Over The Air/half-automatic updates), and it is possible that OTA no longer works for ChaCha.

(I've seen the Facebook button start making trouble, and that slows down the phone to almost unusable levels -- and then it needs either repair or if you install a ROM that ignores the Facebook share button.)

Comment: Thanks @Simon B! I added my versions. Let me know if I gave the right info. I still get no reaction.

Comment: Perhaps my Vol Down key is broken too. Is there a workaround? Any other way to boot into safe mode?

Comment: After thinking more on this, since the home button is a semi-softbutton (touch, but below the actual color display area) I guess your digitizer (touch sensors) are starting to loose functionality.

I have a ChaCha with a flakey Facebook (hardware) button that I can't bring into the boot menu, and this same phone has trouble detecting touch on some parts of the left half of the screen + the home button. So maybe this is a common problem with HTC ChaCha when they get more worn down.

Comment: B: Would that mean an impending dead phone? Or can a mod, new software etc.possibly fix it?

Comment: You could try adding Handy Soft Keys (if ChaCha-compatible, not sure about that) which gives access to Switch/Home/Back buttons as a pull-out menu that you can place somewhere on the screen where it's comfortable and where touch is working well. That should prolong the phone's life a bit.